# Notepadd++ or any editor - custom autocomplete

Tags: javascript, xml, notepad++

I need to trigger a custom auto-complete when user enters a certain XML tag or XML attribute. I would prefer Notepad++.

I know in plugins/API directory there are list of files which contains keywords for auto complete.But it will not be very useful as i need to trigger autocomplete based on certain keyworkds.

The list is very vast so is there any other way to do it ? Currently I use a HTML JavaScript page to render the list. But its not that fruitful.

I want the list to be presented when someone is actually editing the XML page.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: Do you have an XML schema of any kind?

Comment: nothing specific. Jsut example , if i type "text1=" it sould trigger one set of auto complete. If i start typing text2= it should trigger the other set

Comment: That's exactly what a proper XML schema would allow an IDE to accomplish. Too bad you don't have it already—creating one is a pretty good time-consuming task.

Answer (score 0):

In **SynWrite** app: try option (Auto-Complete tab of options): "Auto show list after typing N chars". It works not only for xml.